# Setting the column widths of a dynamically created table to fit contents

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am dynamically creating a table and I want the column widths to shrink/expand to the size of the contents. I have tied:

```
#parTable tr td {
    width: 1%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

And when creating the rows:

```
html += "<tr>"
html += "<td style='width : 1%; white-space: nowrap;'><input type='text' name='patparId' value='' disabled></td>";

html += "<td style='width : 1%; white-space: nowrap;'><select name='parRating'>"
for (let i = 0; i <= paraArray; i++) {
    html += "<option name='parRatingOption' data-index='" + i + "' value='" + parIdArray[i] + "'>" + parRatingArray[i] + "</option>"
};
html += "</select></td>";

html += "<td style='width : 1%; white-space: nowrap;'><input type='date' name='startDate' value=''></td>";
html += "<td style='width : 1%; white-space: nowrap;'><input type='date' name='endDate' value=''></td>";
html += "<td style='width : 1%; white-space: nowrap;'><input type='text' name='parDescription' class='fullWidth' value='" + parDescriptionArray[0] + "'></td>";
html += "<td style='width : 1%; white-space: nowrap;'><input type='button' name='addPARbtn' class='btn-info' value='Add'></td>";
html += "</tr>";
```

The table is:

```
<!-- PAR table -->
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="parTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>patparId</th>
          <th>PAR</th>
          <th>Start Date</th>
          <th>End Date</th>
          <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody id="parTablebody">
        <tr>
            <!-- Place for PAR details -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>                
</table>
```

This is the resulting table:

[image]

Comment: in the html tables the sizes of the columns in width and in height adapt automatically, there is nothing to code, neither in HTML, nor in CSS, nor in Javascript

Comment: @MisterJojo Then why are the columns not shrinking/expanding to size please?

Comment: because you have fixed them to `1%`

Comment: @MisterJojo OK, thank you. Removing the 1% has shrunk the PAR column. However, the date columns are still to wide and the Description column is not wide enough.

Comment: you need to use your browser's inspector to correct your code. From my home it is impossible to see the errors on your computer . https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example